# Ruby : sanitize CSV with irregular fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a CSV file with quite irregular entries. The first entry of a row doesn't have any surrounding quotes, the whole line is quoted, and every field is double quoted like this :

```
# my_file.csv, opened with sublime text :

# Headers
"first_name,""last_name"",""username"",""phone_number"",""address"",""email_address"",""email_address_confirmed"",""joined_at"",""status"",""is_admin"",""accept_emails_from_admin"",""language"",""can_post_listings"""

# Sample entry
"Mr X,""Mr X"",""mrxxx"","""","""",""mr@mrx.com"",""true"",""2015-09-21 09:08:51 UTC"",""accepted"",""true"",""true"",""fr"",""true"""
```

I could preprocess the file using something else than Ruby (Excel, a simple regex/replace, or anything you could think of), but since I am likely to have to do this several times, a Ruby solution would be great.

Currently I am using just

```
csv = File.open(csv_file_path)
CSV.parse(csv, :headers => true)
```

And I don't really see how I could easily fix this difference just for the first entry of each row...

The problem is the CSV is not parsed correctly and instead it considers each row to be one single string (instead of an array with as many items as columns).

```
# csv.headers : note this is an array with a single string
["first_name,\"last_name\",\"username\",\"phone_number\",\"address\",\"email_address\",\"email_address_confirmed\",\"joined_at\",\"status\",\"is_admin\",\"accept_emails_from_admin\",\"language\",\"can_post_listings\""]

# csv.to_a.last
["xxx,\"xxxx\",\"martin\",\"\",\"\",\"xxx@xxxx.com\",\"false\",\"2016-05-12 13:06:53 UTC\",\"pending_email_confirmation\",\"false\",\"true\",\"fr\",\"false\""]
```

EDIT : I have tried the following

```
processed = File.readlines(path).map do |row|
    row.strip                 # strip newlines
      .gsub(/^\"|\"$/, '')   # remove outer quotes
      .gsub(/\"\"/, '"')     # fix double quotes
end
CSV.parse(processed.join('\n'))
```

I run into a `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Missing or stray quote in line 1`

Sample outputs

```
# File.readlines(path).first
# => "\"first_name,\"\"last_name\"\",\"\"username\"\",\"\"phone_number\"\",\"\"address\"\",\"\"email_address\"\",\"\"email_address_confirmed\"\",\"\"joined_at\"\",\"\"status\"\",\"\"is_admin\"\",\"\"accept_emails_from_admin\"\",\"\"language\"\",\"\"can_post_listings\"\"\"\n"

# processed.first
# => "first_name,\"last_name\",\"username\",\"phone_number\",\"address\",\"email_address\",\"email_address_confirmed\",\"joined_at\",\"status\",\"is_admin\",\"accept_emails_from_admin\",\"language\",\"can_post_listings\""
```

EDIT 2

Ouch, I have some nested commas sometimes, and @Dave's answer seem to fail for those cases. There is this field

> ""45, street_addr - Place""

which contains a comma that is not a separator.
The full entry

```
"Mr x,""Mr xx"",""bbernelin"","""",""45, street_addr - Place"",""xxx@xxx.fr"",""true"",""2016-04-13 11:14:08 UTC"",""accepted"",""false"",""true"",""fr"",""true"""
```

Comment: There are more quotes in your example that you say there are in your description. There is a quote at the beginning of each line and two double quotes on each side of each field after the first. I think the answer I posted will work for you either way, but if you made your example match your description we might be able to simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up with :

```
processed = File.readlines(path).map do |row|
    row.strip.gsub('""', '"')[1..-2]
end.join("\n")
CSV.parse(processed)
```

The `[1..-2]` just removes the extra `"` at the beginning/end of the line that was messing up things

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell the whole line has quotes surrounding it, and then some fields are double-quoted.  Fixing that makes the CSV parser happy, so this seems to work:

```
require 'csv'

processed = DATA.map do |row|
  row.strip                 # strip newlines
     .gsub(/^\"|\"$/, '')   # remove outer quotes
     .gsub(/\"\"/, '"')     # fix double quotes
end

CSV.parse(processed.join('\n'), headers: true) do |row|
  p row
end

__END__
"first_name,""last_name"",""username"",""phone_number"",""address"",""email_address"",""email_address_confirmed"",""joined_at"",""status"",""is_admin"",""accept_emails_from_admin"",""language"",""can_post_listings"""
"Mr X,""Mr X"",""mrxxx"","""","""",""mr@mrx.com"",""true"",""2015-09-21 09:08:51 UTC"",""accepted"",""true"",""true"",""fr"",""true"""
```

Results in:

```
#<CSV::Row "first_name":"Mr X" "last_name":"Mr X" "username":"mdxxx"
"phone_number":"" "address":"" "email_address":"mr@mrx.com" 
"email_address_confirmed":"true" "joined_at":"2015-09-21 09:08:51 UTC" 
"status":"accepted" "is_admin":"true" "accept_emails_from_admin":"true" 
"language":"fr" "can_post_listings":"true">
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but I still can't get it to work. Maybe I am reading the file in a bad way ? I have edited my question with additional information.

Comment: My approach is overgeneralized and doesn't handle commas; this is the right approach. I think it doesn't work for Cyril since he has the CSV in a single string. This should work for Cyril either if the regexp in the first `gsub` becomes `/(?<=^|\n)\"|\"(?=$|\n)/` or if Cyril reads the file into an array of strings with e.g. `File#readlines`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are

- 0 or more quotes around each entry
- exactly 1 comma between each entry
- no commas or quotes in any entry

So you can replace all of the quotes around each entry with 1 quote:

```
csv = gsub(/(?<=^|,)"*([^,"\n]*)"*(?=,|$)/, %Q("\\1"))
```

Commented regexp:

```
/
  (?<=^|,)    # pattern is preceded by the beginning of the string or a comma
  "*          # any number of "
  ([^,"\n]*)  # any number of characters, not , " or newline
  "*          # any number of "
  (?=,|$)     # pattern is followed by the end of the string or a comma
/
```

It seems to produce correct results on your example:

```
csv = %Q("first_name,""last_name"",""username"",""phone_number"",""address"",""email_address"",""email_address_confirmed"",""joined_at"",""status"",""is_admin"",""accept_emails_from_admin"",""language"",""can_post_listings"""\n) +
      %Q("Mr X,""Mr X"",""mrxxx"","""","""",""mr@mrx.com"",""true"",""2015-09-21 09:08:51 UTC"",""accepted"",""true"",""true"",""fr"",""true""")
CSV.parse(csv.gsub(/(?<=^|,)"*([^,"\n]*)"*(?=,|$)/, %Q("\\1")), headers: true).to_a
=> [
     ["first_name", "last_name", "username", "phone_number", "address", "email_address", "email_address_confirmed", "joined_at", "status", "is_admin", "accept_emails_from_admin", "language", "can_post_listings"],
     ["Mr X", "Mr X", "mrxxx", "", "", "mr@mrx.com", "true", "2015-09-21 09:08:51 UTC", "accepted", "true", "true", "fr", "true"]
   ]
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is working, however I (realized I) do have some fields with nested commas (street addresses like `Paris, France`). Do you think you can come up with a better regex ? I edited my question to provide an example of such field.